# Java: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 when trying to make Pascal Triangle program

Tags: java, math

The error occurs at line 27, specifically.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PascalTriangle
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //declare scanner
        int [] x = new int [1000]; //declare array x to fill in the numbers of triangle
        x [0] = 1;
        x [1] = 1;
        x [2] = 1;
        int row = 2;
        int num = 0; //numbers displayed per row
        int a = 2; //to be used for array
        int y; //user input
        System.out.println("Pascal Triangle Solver to the nth row");
        System.out.println("Type how many rows you would like to solve");
        y = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(+x[0]+"\n" +x[1]+ " " +x[2]);
        while (row != y)
        {
            System.out.println("\n");
            num = 0;
            row++;
            for(num = 0; row > num; row++)
            {
                x [a+1] = x [a-row] + 1; //where the error occurs
                a++;
                num++;
                System.out.println(+x[a]+ " ");
                while (num < row)
                {
                    x[a] = x [a - row] + x [a - row + 1];
                    System.out.println(+x[a]+ " ");
                    a++;
                    num++;
                }
                x [a+1] = x [a - row];
                a++;
                num++;
                System.out.println(+x[a]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure why exactly it creates an error, so I'm asking for help here.
Any help, tips or guidelines would be much appreciated. Even better if you can help me in formatting this properly like a real Pascal Triangle. Thanks!

Comment: Use a Debugger and find out what is Happening. at one Point `row` is greater than `a` and `a-row` = -1

Comment: This line is suspicious: "for(num = 0; row > num; row++)"

Comment: Very well, I'll be checking those out. When I input 2, the program runs without crashing, but only displays 
1
1 1.
The rest crash. Figured this might be worth sharing.

Comment: You can use a debugger and watch the values of the variables and verify that they are always as expected. But you should make sure first that the structure of your algoritm is clear and that you know exactly what you should expect to find in the variables at any time. You have 3 levels of iteration in your algoritm: a while, a for and within the for again a while. What is each of them meant to do? The outer while iterates the rows, then you need to iterate columns/values on that row. What is the 3th iteration doing? That question exposes the biggest error in your calculation.